# How to join object values into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The current data that I have:

```
const data = [{ persons: [{name: "a", id: 1}], type: 1},
              { persons: [{name: "b", id: 1}], type: 2},
              { persons: [{name: "c", id: 1}], type: 3},
              { persons: [{name: "d", id: 1}], type: 4}]
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
const result = { people: [{names: ["a","b","c","d"], id: 1}], types: [1,2,3,4]}
```

What I have tried to do:

```
const result = data.reduce((result, {persons, type}) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
      if (!result.people[i]) {
        result.people.push({names: [persons[i].name], id: persons[i].id]});
        continue;
      }

      result.people[i].names.push(persons[i].name);
    }    
    
    result.types.push(type);
    return result
}, {people: [], types: []})
```

Is there perhaps a better, more elegant way to approach this?

Comment: So far this looks good.

Comment: Not really, `.reduce` was the best way to handle your case.

Comment: What if the persons have different id??

Answer (score 0):

You may use `{ people: {}, type: {} }` in the `reduce()` to create a hashmap to reduce the loop.

Also, you can extract the data later with `Object.vaues()`

```js
const data = [
  { persons: [{ name: "a", id: 1 }], type: 1 },
  { persons: [{ name: "b", id: 1 }], type: 2 },
  { persons: [{ name: "c", id: 1 }], type: 3 },
  { persons: [{ name: "d", id: 1 }], type: 4 },
  { persons: [{ name: "d", id: 1 }], type: 4 },
  { persons: [{ name: "d", id: 1 }], type: 4 },
  {
    persons: [
      { name: "d", id: 1 },
      { name: "k", id: 2 },
    ],
    type: 4,
  },
];

const groupByData = data.reduce(
  (acc, cur) => {
    for (const person of cur.persons) {
      if (acc.people[person.id]) {
        acc.people[person.id].names.push(person.name);
      } else {
        acc.people[person.id] = { names: [person.name], id: person.id };
      }
    }

    if (!acc.type[cur.type]) {
      acc.type[cur.type] = cur.type;
    }

    return acc;
  },
  { people: {}, type: {} }
);

const output = {
  people: Object.values(groupByData.people),
  types: Object.values(groupByData.type),
};

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const data = [{ persons: [{name: "a", id: 1}], type: 1},
              { persons: [{name: "b", id: 1}], type: 2},
              { persons: [{name: "c", id: 1}], type: 3},
              { persons: [{name: "d", id: 1}], type: 4}]

 const people = []
 const types  = []
 const id = data[0].persons[0].id
 
 const result = data.reduce( (a, p) => {
     people.push(p.persons[0].name)
     types.push(p.type)

     return{
     people:[{names:people , id}] , types
     }
 } , data[0])
console.log(result)
```